# Removing all ()'s from a sublist in Racket

Tags: filter, tree, racket, sublist

I need to have the following program interaction:

```
(clean'(1 (2 () (3 () 4))()()(()) 5)) → (1 (2 (3 4)) 5)
```

This is what I have so far

```
define (emptyClear theList)
  (cond ((null? theList) '())
        ((null? (car theList)) (emptyClear (cdr theList)))
        (else (cons (car theList) (emptyClear (cdr theList))))))

(define (clean tree)
  (cond ((null? tree) '())
        ((not (list? (car tree))) (cons (car tree) (prune (cdr tree))))
        (cons (emptyClear (car tree)) (prune (cdr tree)))))
```

But this gives me: `-> (1 5)` as the output.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example the task seems to be not simply to remove empty lists from a tree, but to *continue* to perform this operation until possible (since `'(())`) is not an empty list, but it is removed nevertheless).

Here is a possible solution, tested with DrRacket.

```
(define (my-empty? x)
  (cond ((null? x) #t)
        ((list? x) (andmap my-empty? x))
        (else #f)))
        
(define (clean x)
  (cond ((null? x) '())
        ((not (list? x)) x)
        ((my-empty? (car x)) (clean (cdr x)))
        (else (cons (clean (car x)) (clean (cdr x))))))

(clean '(1 (2 () (3 () 4))()()((())) 5)) ;=> '(1 (2 (3 4)) 5)
```